# julia parametric constructor

Tags: templates, constructor, julia

Suppose I write the following julia struct:

```
struct Foo{S, T}
    v::Vector{S}
    t::T
end
```

If I want `v` to be empty by default, I can write a custom constructor

```
Foo{Int, String}(t::String) = Foo{Int, String}([], t)
```

Then the following two lines are equivalent:

```
f = Foo{Int, String}([], "hi")
f = Foo{Int, String}("hi")
```

But I can only use the convenient custom constructor for `Foo{Int, String}` objects, not any other type of `Foo`. How can I write a parametric constructor for a `Foo{S, T}` which only takes the value of `t` and initializes `v` empty?

Comment: Try `Foo{S, T}(x::T) where {S, T} = Foo(S[], x)`. Or, possibly, `Foo{S, T}(x::T) where {S, T} = Foo{S, T}(S[], x)`, depending a bit on what other constructors you have defined. Avoid using `[]` in your code, unless strictly required.

Answer (score 1):

Other interesting options beside @DNF's comment:

```
@kwdef struct Foo{S, T}
    v::Vector{S}=S[]
    t::T
end
Foo{S}(t::T) where {S, T} = Foo(S[], t)
```

Than you can do:

```
julia> Foo{Int,Float64}(t=5.0)
Foo{Int64, Float64}(Int64[], 5.0)

julia> Foo{Int}(5.0)
Foo{Int64, Float64}(Int64[], 5.0)
```